# Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '�'

Tags: php, preg-replace

Another question that has been asked a million times, but I'm stuck here.

I'm getting the following error `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '�'` for this line

```
$tweetText = preg_replace('@(?!(?!.*?<a)[^<]*<\/a>)(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)‌​://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-‌​Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]‌​*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]@‌​i','<a href="\0" target="_blank">\0</a>', $tweetText);
```

All I'm trying to do is retrieve a tweet from Twitter(successfully done) but replace the text urls with actual hyperlinks so the user can just click them instead of copy/paste.

The only reason I'm at a loss is because the error is listing `�` so I hadn't got a clue as to which character in that line is wrong.

Any help?

Comment: Did you copy it from an SO comment? :) Remove all the garbage chars, and it will work. See https://regex101.com/r/A2MdIQ/1, copy it from there.

Comment: Look UTF-8 related to me

Comment: Wiktor had no clue about that link you sent so thanks for that. Here's what showed up: `@ An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash (\)` pertaining to the first `@` in that line.

Comment: Your pattern contains no `@` in the pattern - you are definitely using some other regex, not the one posted.

Comment: Moreover, why use a regex on HTML code? Parse it, remove tags you do not want and then run a much simpler regex.

Answer (score 0):

When I paste your code into [hexed.it](https://hexed.it/) I see all kind of extraneous characters right after the ending `@` delimiter:

[image: Screen-shot]

Re-type `@'` and you should get rid of those non-printable chars.

Comment: This is a typo question, no need to answer it.

Comment: I retyped them both before I posted my question assuming it was one of them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree it's a more than likely duplicate but I don't think it's really of typo-type or a bad question per-se.

Comment: No, not a dupe, it is off-topic. It is caused not because of a programming issue, but because of a copy/paste issue. And that makes the question bad. And you do not have to use hexed.it, just copy the OP pattern and paste to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/EYJTwt/1) - you will see the bad ones.

Answer (score 0):

Using the link that @Wiktor Stribiżew provided I was able to see 4 characters that were hidden. Removed them and the error is gone.

Comment: Just remove the question. There was no real issue in the first place.